# Select price range with multiple currencies

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table containing a `currency_code` and  `price`.

```
currency_code | price

usd | 50

twd | 1570

JPY | 5049
```

The user can input a range of `price`s to search the product:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price between 0 and 1500
```

If the `currency_code` is different in the table, how can I make a `price` range query?

Comment: have a currency translation table (that you update often). Join. Represent the query thru a join and conversion to a common currency (dare I suggest dollars). Proceed from there

Comment: you mean add mysql table to store the exchange rate AND join it before query ?

Comment: yep pretty much the deal

Answer (score 0):

You have to control the selected currency and put it into your query:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price between 0 and 1500
AND currency_code = $selected_currency_code
```

Answer (score 0):

From your Question I understand that we have two tables like the following
For ease of understanding Please check these sample

price

```
id  |currency_id    |price
----------------------------
1   |1              |1000
2   |2              |1500
3   |1              |1300
```

currency

```
currency_id |   currency_name
--------------------------------
1           |   Dollor
2           |   Euro
```

This is a sample join query which can output the values between 0 and 1500

```
 SELECT price.id,price.price,currency_code.currency_name FROM price 
INNER JOIN currency_code ON price.currency_id = currency_code.currency_id 
WHERE price  BETWEEN 0 AND 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select driver.*,
case
when driver.rental_currency = 'HKD' then driver_rental.HKT_1_fee_full_day / 7.78
when driver.rental_currency = 'TWD' then driver_rental.HKT_1_fee_full_day / 31.4
when driver.rental_currency = 'CNY' then driver_rental.HKT_1_fee_full_day / 6.67
end
as HKT_1_fee_full_day
from driver_rental
left join driver
on
driver.email = driver_rental.email
where
driver_rental.HKT_1_fee_full_day between 0 and 52
;
```

after using case the where statement between cannot work ?